# Link sql server updates to an app notification

Tags: android, sql-server

So, i want to send a notification to a user of my application on each update on the database table. should i use the timer ? Is there other simple methods??

Comment: sending notification for each update can be overhelming,trying storing all info and send at regular intervals or user defined tiem

Comment: but how? sorry but im new to all this!! @TheGameiswar